# Can't get chrome storage to load anything

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to store an array to chrome storage for an extension but nothing seems stored.
I'm testing with this code (in my content.js)

```
profil="myp";
domain="myd";

datas={};   
datas[profil]={};
datas[profil]['orange']="mure";
datas[profil]['voiture']="rapide";

console.log("to save: "+domain+" "+JSON.stringify(datas));
chrome.storage.sync.set( {domain: datas}, function() { console.log('Settings saved'); } );

//I know I must does that later but the logs are in the right order
datas={};

chrome.storage.sync.get( domain, function(items) 
{ 
    console.log("items: "+JSON.stringify(items)); 
}
```

And the logs:

```
to save: myd {"myp":{"orange":"mure","voiture":"rapide"}}
content.js:147 Settings saved
content.js:154 items: {}
```

I have the permission "storage" in my manifest file.
Is there something I'm forgetting ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chrome.storage.sync.set` and `chrome.storage.sync.get` expect an object, and they use the properties of that object as keys for the store.

When you call `chrome.storage.sync.get` you need an object with a property called `domain`, and the value will be the default if nothing is currently stored.

Try:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get( { domain: [] }, function(items) 
{ 
    console.log("items: "+JSON.stringify(items)); 
}
```

However, it looks like you're using `domain` as a parameter, so:

So:

```
const domain = "myd";

// Store
let store = {};
store[domain] = datas;
chrome.storage.sync.set(store, () => console.log('Settings saved'));

// Retrieve
let key = {};
key[domain] = []; // Default
chrome.storage.sync.get(key, items =>
    console.log(`items: ${JSON.stringify(items)}`));
```

Comment: Seeing your suggestion I tried with a "const domain" but it didn't work, I then replaced domain by "myd" directly and it worked (with my code). I will modify my array to include the domain as it seems (strangely) not possible to use a variable as a "main key"... Anyway thanks for you help.

Comment: I've finally got it after some reflaxion, maybe you should not have modified the way I was declared the function inside the get and set, because it was not the cause of the issue, but thanks.

Comment: @Entretoize The examples are intended to be illustrative, not copy-paste drop-in code. I've no idea how you're declaring your variables, but best practice (enforced if you `'use strict';`) is to always declare them the first time with `var`, `let` (local scope) or `const` (cannot reassign), so I do that in my example. The callback functions are simplified because I'm lazy ;-) In my own code I use [`chrome-extension-async`](https://github.com/KeithHenry/chromeExtensionAsync) with `await` to avoid the callbacks completely.

Comment: In fact sorry I just miss some english vocabulary, I mean I didn't understand the notation "() => console.log('Settings saved')" and it take me some time to understand to issue did not come from that...

Comment: @Entretoize ah - that's an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). It's worth learning how to use them, especially in a Chrome extension where you don't care about IE support.